# How to disable bars in JWebBrowser?

Tags: java, swing

I am using [chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.JWebBrowser](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/documentation/javadoc/chrriis/dj/nativeswing/swtimpl/components/JWebBrowser.html) in my swing application to open web page.
Now my problem is I open the page(url) in browser but on click of any button like facebook it will open other window of browser. I want it to open but with out menu bars in it.
My snippet of code like as below:

```
final JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser(JWebBrowser.destroyOnFinalization());
webBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);
webBrowser.setMenuBarVisible(false);
webBrowser.navigate("http://www.xyz.com/product/myproducts-2");
webBrowser.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with this:

```
webBrowser.addWebBrowserListener(new WebBrowserAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void windowWillOpen(WebBrowserWindowWillOpenEvent e) {

        e.getNewWebBrowser().addWebBrowserListener(new WebBrowserAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void locationChanging(WebBrowserNavigationEvent e) {
                        final JWebBrowser webBrowser = e.getWebBrowser();
                        webBrowser.removeWebBrowserListener(this);
                        webBrowser.setMenuBarVisible(false);
                        webBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);
                        webBrowser.setFocusable(false);

                    }
                });
        }
    }
```

I took it from the [snippets](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/documentation/Snippets.html), specifically the [Navigation Control](http://djproject.cvs.sourceforge.net/%2acheckout%2a/djproject/DJNativeSwing-SWTDemo/src/chrriis/dj/nativeswing/swtimpl/demo/examples/webbrowser/NavigationControl.java?pathrev=R-1_0_1) (direct download) snippet.

You can also look at the WebBrowserAdapter javadoc, inside the [DJ Native Swing documentation](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/documentation/javadoc/index.html).